# Check if input string has only numbers and a max length of 4

Tags: javascript

I need to check if an input string has exactly 4 numbers to prevent an input of invalid characters and longer then 4

```
// maximum of 4 digits
const state = parseInt(value, 10) > -1
  ? parseInt(value, 10).toString().substring(0, 4)
  : ''

// save value if 4 digits or less - which means user is typing...
saveValue(state && state.length <= 4 ? state : '')
```

But with that there could not be a zero at the beginning... and it feels a bit to complicated...

Comment: Try regex: `/^[1-9]\d{3}$/`

Comment: var str = 1234;

console.log(Number(str).toString().length === 4 && str.toString().length === 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using a regex like:

```
/^\d{1,4}$/
```

See the example snippet:

```js
var reg = /^\d{1,4}$/;

console.log(reg.test('1'));
console.log(reg.test('1234'));
console.log(reg.test('12345'));
console.log(reg.test('0001'));
console.log(reg.test('a123'));
console.log(reg.test('123a'));
console.log(reg.test('a000'));
console.log(reg.test('000a'));
```

Output:

```
true    1
true    1234
false   12345
true    0001
false   a123
false   123a
false   a000
false   000a
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = "12345"
console.log(Number(a) && Number(a).toString().length > 4)

a = "123"
console.log(Number(a) && Number(a).toString().length > 4)

a = "0123"
console.log(Number(a) && Number(a).toString().length > 4)

a = "a123"
console.log(Number(a) && Number(a).toString().length > 4)
```

`NaN` also evaluates to `false`

```
saveValue(Number(state) && Number(state).toString().length <= 4 ? state : '')
```

Alternatively use regex `/^[0-9]{0,4}$/`

Answer (score 1):

Short and fast. You can use Regex for that:

```
/^[0-9]{1,4}$/.test(yourVariable);
```

```js
console.log(/^[0-9]{1,4}$/.test('1')); // true
console.log(/^[0-9]{1,4}$/.test('1000')); // true
console.log(/^[0-9]{1,4}$/.test('a')); // false
console.log(/^[0-9]{1,4}$/.test('10000')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```js
 var pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,4}$");
console.log('12', pattern.test('12'));
console.log('123', pattern.test('12'));
console.log('1234', pattern.test('1234'));
console.log('12345', pattern.test('12345'));
console.log('12ab', pattern.test('12ab'));
```